# Problem with questions in past tense

Tags: past-tense, questions

Are these sentences correct?

He was my best friend back in kindergarden.

1. Did he *be* my best friend back in kindergarden?
2. Did he *was* my best friend back in kindergarden?

If #2 is correct, then why isn't the verb BE on its simple form?

He had a Gibson Guitar.

1. Did he *have* a Gibson Guitar?
2. Did he *has* a Gibson Guitar?
3. Did he *had* a Gibson Guitar?

My intuition is telling me that #1 is correct, but i think #3 is correct as well.

I hope someone can answer me, cheers!.

Comment: And much of what I stumbled into by following my curiosity and intuition turned  out to be priceless later on.”: Steve Jobs

Comment: Neither of your first two questions is correct.  As Harsh Sharma says, the correct way to phrase is it "Was he...?"  As a general rule, you can't use *did* with *to be* - you can say "Did he eat? or "Did he run?" etc., but to make a question about *to be*-statements, you just use *to be*: "Is she tall?" or "Was she there?" etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial sentences are wrong.  Did can't be used in that manner.  Instead,  use of 'was' is much more preferable.  You can say: Was he my friend back in kindergarten?

In the second question,  note the fact that with 'did'  we must use a present tense verb form only since 'did'  had itself carried the reference to past tense, so we are left with only two options 'has'  and 'have'.  But one more crucial thing to note is that 'did'  requires the use of 'have' since it is an auxiliary verb  in the sentence.  Usage of auxiluary word requires use of bare infinitive.

Correct: She didn't have a watch. 
INCORRECT: She didn't has a watch.